# Object class couldn't be converted to string Laravel 5

Tags: string, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

When I return the request of my controller, I get:

> {"employees":"3","reason":"common 
>      reason","request":"5000","ded_per_pay":"500","months_to_pay":"2","date_issued":"2018-01-31"}

And in my create function, I get this error:

**Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag could not be converted to string**

Here's my code:

```
     CashAdvance::create([
        'emp_id' => $request->employees,
        'reason' => $request->reason,
        'request' => $request->request,
        'ded_per_pay' => $request->ded_per_pay,
        'date_issued' => $request->date_issued,
        'months_to_pay' => $request->months_to_pay
    ]);
```

What seems to be causing the problem??

Comment: `dd($request->request);` outputs  `ParameterBag` class's object, whereas we expect to save a string in table. Use `$request->get('request')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is really interesting. I've had a look in the [API docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/Request.html) and it appears that the Request object has a parameter `request`. Which means that when you are calling `$request->request`, you are getting the parameter bag from your `$request`.

To get around this, you can use something like:

`$myRequest = $request->input('request');`

But I would heavily advise that instead you rename `request` to something that won't confuse yourself/other devs later in the project, and to keep these special named variables reserved for what they actually mean.